# What is an umbrella terms for billboards, newspaper and TV ads, etc. that are used to promote a candidate for a public office?

Tags: word-request

I believe it's 'campaign [something]' but I'm not sure what that something is. 'Campaign materials', perhaps? What term would include both offline and online campaign ads?

Comment: Electoral (or election) campaign/s is what you are seeking.   https://openelectiondata.net/en/guide/key-categories/election-campaigns/

Comment: @RonaldSole: I'd say an electoral campaign is a *process* - within which billboards, newspaper and TV ads, facebook pages, etc. are "vehicles, channels" [of communication] - or "media", but these days that would often be understood to specifically mean *[mainstream] **mass** media*, not things like leaflets or car bumper stickers.

Comment: Campaign _publicity_ is a thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is it *the* thing?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't need *a* thing, I need *the* thing: the term that fits my description. You said it as though it's just one of the numerous idiomatic phrases used in English, not necessarily the one I'm seeking

Comment: To say that a phrase, word, or expression is 'a thing' means that it is valid, current and widely understood. 'Campaign materials' would be used for paper leaflets, posters, stickers, etc, but 'campaign publicity' is wider because it covers these and also TV ads, web videos, and other non-material methods of reaching voters.

Comment: Online media revenue from advertising for Romanian Euro-parliamentary elections will not exceed €200,000, according to the General Manager and Strategic Planner of web agency Webstyler, Bogdan Nitu. Sources on the market suggest that some 60 percent of total electoral **campaign publicity**, costing some €120,000, will go to online advertising agency AdEvolution.

Comment: Your question sounds like a trick question. Both red and white bricks are still *bricks*. Both *online* and *offline* campaign ads are still ***campaign ads***.